# How can I pass 2 values in a function?

Tags: c, function, arguments, syntax-error

Right now I'm trying to pass the name and argc into the vote function

but I get a bunch of errors, the argc doesn't work, how do I pass that in?

I have 2 errors saying I have to many arguments in my function call.

It says it only expected one argument.

```
int main(int argc, string argv[]) // I want to pass this argc parameter into my vote function
{
    // Check for invalid usage
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: plurality [candidate ...]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Populate array of candidates
    candidate_count = argc - 1;
    if (candidate_count > MAX)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", MAX);
        return 2;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        candidates[i].name = argv[i + 1];
        candidates[i].votes = 0;
    }

    int voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");

    // Loop over all voters
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        string name = get_string("Vote: ");

        // Check for invalid vote
        if (!vote(name, argc)) // it doesn't work here
        {
            printf("Invalid vote.\n");
        }
    }

    // Display winner of election
    print_winner();

bool vote(string name, int argc) // and here
{
    // TODO
    return false;
}

}
```

[image]

Comment: Read [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) about `struct` and pointers to them. BTW `string` does not exist in standard C. Read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) and take inspiration from existing open source programs like [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) - which is mostly written in C. Provide some [mre] in your question. Use the  [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look at structs and next time I will try to put less code in so its more understandable

Comment: Is this C++ `string` or CS-50 trash course `string`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in the last error:

> plurality.c:23:6: previous declaration is here

> bool vote(string name);

You've got a prototype that you have to fix